# How to open a URL in Firefox\Chrome from command line in pop up mode?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, command-line

When executing the following command line:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://aaa.com" --new-window
```

it opens the browser in a new window but with all the toolbars - how can I open the browser like a popup?

Answer (score 15):

Maybe "application mode" is what you are looking for.

Here's an example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="http://www.youtube.com/"
```

Comment: Using "Program Files (x86)" worked for me, like so:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="http://www.youtube.com/"`

Answer (score 4):

This might Help

> How can I launch a browser with no window frame or tabs/address bar

https://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar

> Following site lists all command line switches for chrome

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 4):

in Mozilla FireFox you can do it like

```
firefox.exe -new-window "www.google.com"
firefox.exe -new-tab "www.google.com"
```

in Google Chrome you can do it like

```
chrome.exe --app="www.google.com"
chrome.exe --kiosk "www.google.com"
```

Comment: This does not open windows chromelessly on Firefox.

Comment: @Paul i tested its working can u try from cmd : chrome.exe --kiosk "www.google.com"